# Python copy or print Hyperlink

Tags: python, hyperlink, copy, urllib2

Hey I would like to copy or print the hyperlink from a word.

for example: [Gift Cards](http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=topnav_giftcert?ie=UTF8&node=3063530011)

With which code is this possible?

Can I use urllib2?

If somebody speaks German it would be simpler :)

Comment: Are you grabbing the words from a website?

Comment: Yes with: htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('*link*')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)
a_tag = soup.find('a') # This finds the first occurrence of an a tag.
print a_tag['href'] # Prints the link which the a_tag links to. (hyperlink)
```

Of course this is pretty basic code. If you look at the documentation of the module, you'll see many other methods you can use to achieve your results :)

Comment: What is ['href'] in the last line?

Comment: @user2534685 Okay so you know how in an a tag there is something like `<a href=http://hyperlink.com>Foo</a>` ?. What `'href'` does is accesses the `http://hyperlink.com`

Comment: On a lot of web pages in the source code is also a hyperlink. For example: href='/b/ref=topnav_giftcert?ie=UTF8&node=3063530011' class='nav_a'>Gift Cards</a></li>

Comment: @user2534685 Yes, there could be many. You can use `find_all()`, which finds all the a tags on the page

Comment: But I get with the Code find_all() for example only: /gp/prime/signup/videos. The Hyperlink is: http://www.amazon.com/gp/prime/signup/videos/ref=nav_prime_join

Comment: @user2534685 Did you do `find_all('a')`?  If you want to get specific a tags, check out the link I posted in my answer. It links documentation you can read which is very simple to follow.